# Text replacing macros

Tags: c++

Given such a small app

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class IGraph
{

};

#define NULLWrapper(n) class IG ##nWrapperNULL : public I##n 

class Test : public IGraph
{

};

NULLWrapper(Graph)
{

};

int main()
{
    IGnWrapperNULL gw;
    IGGraphWrapperNULL gw;

    return 0;
}
```

Why Visual Studio 2015 says that `IGGraphWrapperNULL` is undefined, while `IGnWrapperNULL` is correct? Shouldn't `##n` be replaced with the value I'm sending in macros parameters?

Comment: You can generate a preprocessed file in Visual Studio.  That would show you what the compiler is seeing.  Both of your variables in main can't have the same name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `##` is not used to "stringify" a macro parameter, its used to concatenate strings. The proper define would be:

```
#define NULLWrapper(n) class IG##n##WrapperNULL : public I##n
```